# Flutter - How to center widget inside list view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm struggling with centering a widget inside `listView`.

I tried this, but `Text('ABC')` is not centered vertically.
How can I achieve this?

```
new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: new ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    children: [
      new Center(
        child: new Text('ABC')
      )
    ]
  )
);
```

Comment: Why are you using a ListView for that?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Vertically Center & Horizontal Center:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: Center(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: [
          Center(child: new Text('ABC'))
        ]
    ),
  ),
);
```

Only Vertical Center

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: Center(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: [
          new Text('ABC')
        ]
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This works. But I have a list of child, so I have to put on every child a center-widget :(
Hope Flutter comes with a alignment-property on the Listview...

Comment: Bless your soul! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: This works but `shrinkWrap: true` makes the page not scrollable.

Comment: This didn't work for me and the logic you used to achieve this result is absolutely not clear, please add some comments.

Comment: in iOS you can still scroll, and it looks bad

Answer (score 64):

Solving this question with `shrinkWrap = true` is a hack. The whole point of centering widgets inside a `ListView` is to have bounciness and scrolling enabled. Using `shrinkWrap` doesn't achieve this, it looks visually correct but it behaves completely wrong.

The solution is to place a `Container` as the only children in the `ListView`, and give it a minimum height equal to the available space for the height (Use `LayoutBuilder` to measure the maximum height for the widget). Then as the `Container`'s child, you can either place a `Center` or `Column` (with MainAxisAlignment.center) widget and from there you can add whatever widgets you intended to center.

Below is the code to solve the example in the question:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('ABC'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, shrinkWrap probably isn't what you want to use, although ideally ListView should have a better way to implement this. For my cases specifically, I need a ListView so that I can trigger a RefreshIndicator. Thanks.

Comment: @kapace thanks for the nice words. i just updated my answer to be way cleaner and easier to understand. i hope you like it!

Comment: In my case, this is the only working solution.
I need a menu on top of the listview, and activityIndicator on the center.
Thanx.

Comment: Nice solution, unless you are working on a login/registration form (like me). There you will notice that the keyboard will close immediately after being opened. This problem doesn't happen with `shrinkView: true`. Using the keyboard is the only thing that forces me to use `ListView` instead of `Column`.

Comment: @HamzaAbbad, I found that bug happening to me too, but has nothing to do with centering using a `ListView`. The bug is related with `AutofillGroup` on iOS. If you take `AutofillGroup` out, then the keyboard should work properly. Still waiting for the flutter to release a fix.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me nuts, and now that I see how to do it I am face-palming that I didn't think of it before.

Comment: You may want use `shrinkwrap: true,`, just remember that doing that you need to also set the desired `physics` property.

Comment: I'd like to add that in addition to optionally using `Column` with `MainAxisAlign.center`, it is also possible to simulate a traditional full screen interface using `MainAxisAlign.spaceBetween` too to put a title at the top edge and buttons at the bottom edge, while also allowing the screen the scroll if overflowed.

Comment: Works like charm! but had to set the `mainAxisSize of the column` to `mainAxisSize.max` for this solution to work for my use case

Answer (score 23):

Wrap your widget into container

```
Container(alignment: Alignment.center, ...)
```

or

```
Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, ...)
```

Answer (score 13):

[image]

---

Simply wrap your widget in `Align` and provide `alignment` accordingly.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView( // your ListView
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: _button("Left"),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: _button("Middle"),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: _button("Right"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _button(text) => RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text(text));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `Align` inside your `ListView` which will render Widgets at the center, Also we don't have to give any alignment property as by default it is center

This will add `ListView` at the center of the screen, as the list item increases it will grow from the center only.

```
   Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, // Axis.horizontal for horizontal list view.
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Align(child: Text('Text'));
          },
        ),
      ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: First you don't need to use `Center` as parent for your `ListView`, second scrollDirection is vertical by default, third, I have already provided `Align` as a solution to center the widget. I don't see any value in your answer and thus it should be deleted, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad: It will draw ListView from the center of the screen, I know the question is about widget under listview.  This is another way where add Listview at the center as well as child Text

Comment: So, you only want to add `Center` to your `ListView` for the question, right? Well even then you're not correct, no matter if you wrap your `ListView` inside `Center` or not, it won't make any difference. So, your answer actually carries no meaning. Correct me again if I am wrong.

Comment: it did center the widget, but listview still not scrollable

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most elegant way would be to use `ClampingScrollPhysics`, so the content is only scrollable if needed.
Example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
            children: <Widget>[
.... your list of widgets ...
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer 

Comment: @daibaku please mark as accepted answer if this answers your issue 

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Align widget to center a child widget vertically and/or horizontally:

```
   Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'middle',
    ),
```

**Note**: if you have a column as a child, you will have to add :

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
```

to the column to align it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the item in the center to scroll then do the following.

```
Center(
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: [
      // the container with height will make the screen scroll
      Container(
        height:
             MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
        child: Text('ABC'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Tip: give the container a color to visualize the areas that can scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: Doctor.listOfDoctors.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        String name = Doctor.listOfDoctors[index].name;
                        String details = Doctor.listOfDoctors[index].info;
                        //better for design is to use ListTile instead of Text Widget
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            name,
//this is how I solved this issue ;)
                            **textAlign: TextAlign.center,**
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CustomScrollView` and `SliverFillRemaining`  instead of using `ListView`.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Center(
          child: new Text('ABC')
        ),
      ),
    ]
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this container in your listview

```
Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "No Record Found",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 237, 237),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'images/logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  width: 130,
                )
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: TextStyle_Title(
                    text: 'سلاااام',
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```