# How to vertical align ListView in the middle

Tags: dart, flutter

I want my list item in the middle of the `ListView`

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
    List<String> listName = ['Woody', 'Buzz', 'Rex'];

    return Container
    (
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.pinkAccent)),
      width: 400,
      height: 700,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: ListView.builder
      (
        itemCount: listName.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index)
        {
          return OurName(listName[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

This is when I use `shrinkWrap`, when I scroll up it's cut off and it can't be scroll down
[shrinkWrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy6JK.gif)

This is what I expected [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq7ZY.gif)

Answer (score 10):

The key to your issue is the `shrinkWrap` property of `ListView`. So to fix this you can do something like this:

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text("The index$index");
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 30,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: if I use `shrinkwrap`, the height of my `ListView` not 700 or as height as the screen anymore

Comment: @cyclick You could set the height of the container to be 700 and the result will be the same and the list will update the height based on the content with a max height equal with the container height.

Answer (score 4):

For me works this code!

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount:rows.length,
          itemBuilder: (
            context,
            index,
          ) {
            return ...;
          }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here to center vertically (and horizontally) my listView, and came up with this:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<String> listName = ['Woody', 'Buzz', 'Rex'];

    return Align(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listName.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Center(child: Text(listName[index]));
        },
        shrinkWrap: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont get what you mean do you want to align the whole listview then use a center widget and align the listview in the center, or use Align widget and manually align it by

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: //here your list,
)
```

if thats not what you want or doesn't get the job done then please explain more.

Comment: what I want to center it is the item in the listview

Comment: i really dont see the need to do so but one question in mind to help you better is  there any other elements in the list?

Comment: @danypata this is what I expected [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq7ZY.gif), I have no problem doing it in feathers [link](https://feathersui.com) (AS3), I want to port my app to flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991376/flutter-how-to-center-widget-inside-list-view

Comment: is this what are you looking for?