# How to center an Item inside ListView

Tags: flutter

Suppose I have a List of integer numbers between 0-1000
suppose picture below:

[image: Chance Spinner]

but instead of fruits , I want to show the number.
now I have 3 problem:

1:as you know at last the item must be centered in its box , how can I do that inside ListView

2:I should only controll the ListView with controllers and user shouldn't move it.

3:how to gradually spin it ?

this is my code:

```
class SpinnerChance extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpinnerChanceState createState() => _SpinnerChanceState();
}

class _SpinnerChanceState extends State<SpinnerChance>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation1;
  Animation<double> _animation2;
  Animation<double> _animation3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    _animation1 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 100.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _animation2 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 30.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _animation3 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 10.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  List<Widget> items = [];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(_animation1?.value?.toStringAsFixed(1) ??
                    "You Dont Spin It Yet"),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(_animation2?.value?.toStringAsFixed(1) ??
                    "You Dont Spin It Yet"),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(_animation3?.value?.toStringAsFixed(1) ??
                    "You Dont Spin It Yet"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Spin!"),
            onPressed: () {
              _animationController.forward();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside your column, wrap with `Expanded` for the widget that you want to centered. try aligin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991376/flutter-how-to-center-widget-inside-list-view

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine there's a lot of ways to create the effect you want. It's basically a slot machine but instead of fruits, you use numbers.

I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@vkonuhova/rollerlist-or-howto-slot-machine-in-flutter-b042145bdb4b) which answers most of your questions on how to achieve the animation and as for how to turn it into numbers, you could use `Text` widgets instead of images since you would only need the numbers 0-9.

This isn't completely connected to `ListView`s in general but if you want to center its item then wrap the specific widget you want to center inside an `Align` widget, something like so:

```dart
Align(
   alignment: Alignment.center
   child: yourWidgetHere
),
```